# Twitter 401 Authentication Error (Does Thread.sleep() unsyncs me clock)

Tags: twitter, clock, synchronization

I have given a lot of thought before posting this questions. I have several issues regarding `Twitter` and `Twitter4j` API. I am collecting followers of users from Twitter. It runs well for some time and then show the error

```
401:Authentication credentials ( http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key cret, access token cret, and the system clock in in sync.
error - Timestamp out of bounds
request - /1/account erify_credentials.json?include_entities=false
Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6f0f59ca or
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=3f8a87d4
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f0f59ca-3f8a87d4], statusCode=401, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.2.0}
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:189)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:65)
at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:93)
at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:131)
at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:1150)
at com.xinlab.blueapple.twitterrobot.ConvertRobot$1.run(ConvertRobot.java:77)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:317)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:150)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:98)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.runPeriodic(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:181)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:205)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Failed to get mentions: 401:Authentication credentials ( http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key cret, access token cret, and the system clock in in sync.
error - Timestamp out of bounds
request - /1/account erify_credentials.json?include_entities=false
```

I have looked on the web but didn't get the right answer. Some guys suggested to sync your clock but nobody mentioned how to sync(I don't know this is the problem or not, there might be some other problem).

Credential can not be wrong as it works fine for **15-20 min**. I also would like to tell that I am also using `Thread.sleep(x)`as Twitter doesn't allow to request more than 350 queries per hour.

So if the problem is in time synchronization as most of the users said in other posts then is that something to do with `Thread.sleep(12000)`

Update: I figured out that the point at which I am getting error is the time when Twitter asks for followers from a user whose tweet is protected. Is is something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion to sync your clock is because the request has a timestamp that is used to seed the hash algorithm when it generates a signature used to validate the request.

The signature is specific to the request being made, the person making it, the application making it, when it was made, and another random value.

Requests are time sensitive, so the service (Twitter) will check that the timestamp falls within a +/- time. The exact time is unknown, but the service should make it as small as is feasible.

You should sync your system clock using an internet time service. Here is an article that Google provided me on setting the time in linux: http://www.go2linux.org/how-to-set-the-date-and-time-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Yes the suggestion is to check/sync your clock. I tried to do same and I kept on updating my system time(Laptop/PC). After 1Hour I came to notice that my emulator's system time was not on sync with the server. I stopped emulator and started again It worked. Also you can manually change the system time from:

1. Settings
2. Date and Time
3. Untick Automatic Date and Time
4. Set Time

Hope this helps someone.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

- Please go to "Date and Time Settings"
- Set Time automatically to ON
- Restart you Emulator

[image]